# Quantas semanas há no mês com PHP

Tags: php

Pessoal preciso saber como calcular quantas semanas há em um respectivo mês com PHP.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo no [soen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5459292)

```
$mes = 2;
$ano = 2016;
$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes, $ano);

$week_day = date("N", mktime(0,0,0,1, $mes, $ano));

$weeks = ceil(($days + $week_day) / 7);

echo $weeks;
```